# About malloc behavior in pthread

Tags: c, pthreads, malloc

My program is divided into 2 parts:

1. The library file (libprog.c), with only one function:

   ```
   int *
   libfunc(void)
   {
       int     *i;

       i = malloc (sizeof(int));

       printf("in lib, %d\n", *i);
       return i;
   }
   ```
2. The main program (prog.c):

   ```
   void *
   thr_func(void *arg)
   {
       int     *p;

       p = libfunc();
       printf("in thr: %d\n", *p);

       return (void *)0;
   }

   int
   main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
       pthread_t       tid;

       pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thr_func, NULL);
       pthread_join(tid, NULL);

       return 0;
   }
   ```

As you can see, I'm just creating one pthread and passing `thr_func()` function to it which in turn calls `libfunc()`, which allocates one integer using `malloc()` and returns its pointer.
When I run this program, it prints the integer `i` in `libfunc()`, but gives segmentation fault when I try to access it in `thr_func()`, it gives segfault:

```
bash-4.1$ ./prog
in lib, 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But when I remove the thread creation using pthread and call `thr_func()` directly in `main()`, the program runs successfully:

```
bash-4.1$ ./prog
in lib, 0
in thr: 0
```

So how is pthread affecting the way memory is accessed here?
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: You better ask first about the behavior of printing an uninitialized memory location...

Comment: I wouldn't trust the C std library to be thread-safe.

Comment: How did you build this ? (ie. the exact compilation commands used)

Comment: I know I'm printing an uninitialized memory location, but isn't every variable gets zero value by default? (they just point to a particular offset in the zeroed out memory page)
Anyway, that's not my concern.

Comment: I built it like this:

1) First, build the source file which I'm using here (libprog.c):
# gcc libprog.c -c

2) Build the main program (prog.c):
# gcc -lpthread -o prog prog.c libprog.o

Comment: @Ajk: You should be passing the `-pthread` option to both compilation commands (note that this option implies `-lpthread` so you don't need that as well for the second one).

Comment: @caf I did that too, but didn't work.
# gcc -pthread libprog.c -c
# gcc -pthread -o prog prog.c libprog.o

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your prog.c compilation unit doesn't see a declaration for the `libfunc` function. So, the following (default) declaration is used instead :

```
int libfunc();
```

Note that this is different from the real one :

```
int* libfunc();
```

Now, when `libfunc` is called from `thr_func`, the returned `int*` pointer is interpreted as an `int`, and then cast back to an `int*` when storing it in the local `p` variable. The result of casting an `int` to a pointer type is implementation defined. On your platform, this resulted in a messed up pointer value, which ended up causing a segmentation fault.

To fix this, add the following line to the top of prog.c :

```
int* libfunc();
```

Or better yet, create a proper header file that goes with libprog.c.

Comment: You're absolutely right, Sander. It worked.
Thanks a ton..
But this raises one more question: why does it happen only in case of pthread? Why not in normal scenario?

Comment: @Ajk : what happens when you cast an `int` to a pointer type is implementation defined. Maybe it works for some pointer values (eg. non-negative values), and not for others.